# How many 9-card hands contain four cards of the same value?

Tags: combinations, card-games

There are 52 cards, 4 suits, each suits have 13 differences value.

`step1 -> There are 13 difference case, 13C1 = 13`

`step2 -> Without 4 cards, the remaining cards is 48.And we need to pick up other 5 cards. 48C5`

Then 13 * 48C5 is the answer for How many 9-card hands contain four cards of the same value.
But the answer is incorrect, so i need some hints,Thanks!.

Comment: Does a hand like $2222KKKKQ$ count?

Comment: You need to specify clearly what restrictions, if any, are there on the remaining cards.

Answer (score 4):

In $13\cdot \binom{48}{5} $ you counted two times the cases where there are TWO distinct values with four cards, so you have to subtract $\binom{13}{2}\cdot (52-8)$.

Comment: It is as easy as **P.I.E.** (the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion).